# Django - multiply two queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class Sales(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantité = models.IntegerField()
```

I defined two querysets:

```py
Product = Product.objects.all()
Sales = Sales.objects.all()
```

How can I have a queryset of the total amount sold by each product?

Something like - product x has y amount of sales

Comment: How do you require the result query set? Only a list of product and their sales or with all the fields of product model accompanied by the total sales of that product?

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the `Product` queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Product.objects.annotate(
    total_sold=F('Price') * Sum('sales__Quantité')
)
```

The `Product` objects that arise from *this* queryset will contain an extra attribute `.total_sold` that contains the `price` multiplied by the sum of the related `Quantité`s of the related `Sales` objects.